# Rust: Tokio + Warp run in background

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, rust-tokio, rust-warp

Rust newbie here since I recently started working on it. I'm trying get a rest api working and the following code works completely fine for me.

MyRest.rs

```
pub struct RestBro;

impl RestBro {

    pub async fn run_bro() {
        let routes_post = warp::post()
            .and(warp::path!("v1" / "homie").and_then(my_function));

        warp::serve(routes)
            .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3003))
            .await;    
    }

}
```

main.rs

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let rb = RestBro;
    rb.run_bro().await;
}
```

Now the thing is that I don't want my main to be an `async` and I just can't figure out how to run that `run_bro()` function indefinitely like its happening above. I've tried `block_on` and that just blocks and waits for `run_bro` to interrupt which is expected and when I tried `spawn` it just runs through and exits. The documentation on Tokio confused me and that's why I'm looking for some help here.

**block_on**

```
fn main() {
    let async_block = async {
        let rb = RestBro;
        rb.run_bro().await;
    };
    let tr = tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap();
    tr.block_on(async_block);
    println!("Everything working good!");
}
```

**spawn**

```
fn main() {
    let tr = tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap();
    tr.spawn(async {
        let rb = RestBro;
        rb.run_bro().await;
    });
    println!("Everything working good!");
}
```

To be clear, my question is how can I call asynchronous `run_bro()` function and await from a synchronous main?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is the actual question ?

Comment: This (https://blog.joco.dev/posts/warp_auth_server_tutorial) help you ?

Comment: I updated my post with a question which is more clear. Basically how can I call asynchronous run_bro() function and await from a synchronous main?

Comment: Why do you want your main function not to be async?

Comment: Because other that main function will be starting other services and doing some other operations unrelated to warp. Also since main is async I'll have to have all other functions async.

Answer (score 1):

> To be clear, my question is how can I call asynchronous  run_bro()
> function and await from a synchronous main?

I do not understand why you'd want to wrap `server` in `spawn`. In your code, it's not working because your main program closes and the `spawn` closes with it.

```
fn main() {
    let tr = tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap();
    tr.spawn(async {
        let rb = RestBro;
        rb.run_bro().await;
    });
    println!("Everything working good!");
}
```

If you change it to this it'll work for five seconds.

```
use std::{thread, time};

fn main() {
    let tr = tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap();
    tr.spawn(async {
        let rb = RestBro;
        rb.run_bro().await;
    });
    println!("Everything working good!");
    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(5));
}
```

Or indefinitely:

```
fn main() {
    let tr = tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap();
    tr.spawn(async {
        let rb = RestBro;
        rb.run_bro().await;
    });
    println!("Everything working good!");
    tr.join().unwrap();
}
```